# Using Jmeter, How should Ijmeter generate a UUID for Order and send it in the request body (which is coming from CSV file)

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

Using Jmeter, I'm sending API request body from a CSV file. The request body have multiple orders and it should be UUID. So for each iteration, I should generate a UUID for Order and send it in the request body (which is coming from CSV file)

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [__UUID function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions), it generates an [UUID v4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) structure each time it's being called so it's enough to just put `${__UUID}` in the place you need the UUID and JMeter will generate it in the runtime:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: So I'm sending this in the CSV file "batchOrders": [    {      "orderId": "${__UUID}" , and OrderID should generate UUID value. But this is the request I see in results ""batchOrders": [    {      "orderId": "${__UUID}".  OrderID is not generating UUID.